# How do I test static variables using Database.Stateful across batch runs

Tags: batch, stateful

I am using a class that implements `Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful` and I need to test it. In the `finish()` function, I generate and store some records based on information collected throughout the run that HAS to be accurate. When I test this I get:

```
System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.
```

I'm creating **two** records and trying to process one at a time...

```
    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchReallyCoolProcess(), 1);
    Test.stopTest();
```

Is it possible to test this or do I have to trust it works?

*Edit:*

The problem here is that while running a test it fails if the batch takes more than one execution to complete... The purpose of Database.Stateful is to retain some values across executions...

So, how do I test static values that remain by using Database.Stateful if I cannot test more than one execution?

Comment: When you say "static variables", do you really mean declared with "static"? If so, static variables do not retain values from transaction to another. Instead you need the values to be normal class attributes (non-static) initialized in `start`, for example, updated in `execute` and used in `finish`. These will be easily testable by declaring them as test visible.

Comment: The only way to share data between multiple batch executions is to either have the batches chain each other, passing the values forward, or to store the values in the database.

Comment: The problem is declaring the variables but breaking the batch up.. by passing 1 to the second parameter of Database.executeBatch(), it runs the batch twice which throws the error (I believe)

Comment: This isn't running the batch twice, but calls `execute` multiple times, once per chunk. This is how batches are supposed to work, to allow you to process up to 50 million records based on a query locator in much smaller and manageable chunks. I don't understand what you're trying to do. You will need to post snippets of the batch code (from start, execute and finish) to allow the community to understand what you're doing and where you're stuck.

Comment: @PhilW if I remove the second param, the 1, the test runs. In the real world, my records may come in a split across executions... The functionality I am trying to test relies on data being retained between executions. Is there a way to test this?

Comment: If you mean between calls to separate batch instances, you probably need a custom object to hold the data.

Comment: I feel like this may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) as written. What are you doing that requires two batch executions? Are you doubting that Database.Stateful works? Or your design? Can it be written differently?

Comment: @sfdcfox I am just wondering if there is a way to test the functionality of Database.Stateful because if you try to run multiple executions of a batch process the test fails.

Comment: Testing Database.Stateful directly is like testing to make sure that 1+1=2. Database.Stateful does work in the general sense. Just don't expect static variables to retain their data; the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) states this explicitly.

Comment: I see my thinking error. I had it backwards. I was thinking static variables would retain value. smh. But that's why we test right?